# Why might the Q_FOREACH macro break VS2010 intellisense?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, macros, intellisense

I have a c++ project in VS2010 with Qt 4.7.4 and I frequently have problems with IntelliSense (as we all do...). A specific problem is that sometimes the function body (in the .cpp file) can't be found. If I click into that function body, the dropdown box (which usually shows the function you're in) is empty.

Today I noticed this behavior right after I added a `foreach()` statement (the Qt macro Q_FOREACH). I then replaced the foreach() macro with a corresponding `for(int i = 0; i < ...)` and IntelliSense *immediately* displayed the function again.

So I'd like to know:

1. Can somebody please verify this behavior and tell me so in a comment?
2. *Why* does this happen?
3. Is there a workaround which lets me continue to use Q_FOREACH?

Comment: I can't verify it as I only have 2008 and Intellisense is so overwhelmed by our rather large project that it has so many issues it's hard to make it work at all. But here's what I am doing: I'm *developping* in Qt Creator and *compiling and debugging* in Visual Studio. This appeared as the best combination of the two worlds for me. Obviously you need to manage projects in `.pro` files and convert them using `qmake -tp vc -recursive <project>.pro` or a visual studio add in

Comment: what happens when you replace `foreach()` by `Q_FOREACH` and specify `CONFIG += no_keywords`??

Comment: @UmNyobe I tried replacing `foreach()` by `Q_FOREACH` with no effect. I'm afraid I don't know how to add `no_keywords`, because in VS2010 there are no `.pro` files. Do you know which is the corresponding field in the project property pages? However, `no_keywords` would mean I'd have to replace all `signal`s by `Q_SIGNAL` - this is way more cumbersome than rewriting all foreachs().

Comment: How well does intellisense handle preprocessor macros?

Comment: Look at how Q_FOREACH is implemented. It's a tangle of macros and templates doing some serious magic for you. I'd wager VS is just tripping up with the combination of that magic and whatever you're passing to it

Comment: @cppguy So without reverse-engineering or debugging VS intellisense, your comment probably is the best answer to question 2.

Comment: Feel free to upvote it then. It's too short and anecdotal to be in an answer :)

Comment: I have boiled the problem down to a simple test case. see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480235/function-definitions-missing-from-intellisense-in-visual-studio-c-2005-2013
So it is NOT a matter of overly complicated (Qt) macro magic.

Comment: So everybody using Qt (with VS) must have experienced the same problem for years... So strange that no one seems to care.

Comment: here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781121/c-intellisense-mistakes-loop-expression-for-function-definition
somebody has about the exact same problem, but he did not make the point clear enough.

Comment: @NoEscape Thanks for the links. This indeed might have something to do with what you found.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the thanks. But please replace 'might have to do' with: 'All 3 are exactly the same intellisense problem/bug'

Comment: Yet another link describing it is http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588308/vs2010-c-intellisense-treats-preprocessor-macros-as-functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the concept of 'cpp.hint' files.

Basically, you have to put the troublesome macros into a file named 'cpp.hint' and put that file in your solution directory (which did not work for me - non-standard project layout maybe) OR in a parent-directory where your code files reside in. (worked for me)

In that file you just put the troublesome macros WITHOUT right-hand-side, so in your case:

```
#define foreach()
```

or maybe better

```
#define Q_FOREACH(variable, container)
#define foreach(...)
etc.
```

NOTE, that you may have to ReScan or Restart or fiddle around with a function for the effect to set in after putting the definition in the cpp.hint file.

**UPDATE**: Indeed, I just found, that I have to make some change to a .cpp file (e.g. adding a new line) for the effect to kick in. The fix is not automatically applied.

The original link is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997977.aspx

The reason for the trouble is that Intellisense performance would (potentially) decrease dramatically if it had to parse all macros in a project, so it only parses those given explicitly in 'cpp.hint'.

The original microsoft text says that you can use any directory in "The path from the root directory of a source file to the directory that contains the source file itself. In a typical Visual C++ project, the root directory contains the solution or project file."

You can find the main 'cpp.hint' file at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcpackages' for reference